# I want to copy an old database. I only have the creation scripts

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I want to create a database on MariaDB using some old scripts from a MySQL database I made some years ago. I only have the creation scripts I used (.ipynb), and I was wondering how could I recreate the database if possible.

The old database should still be on my PC but I can't find it. I installed MariaDB on it and now when I open MySQL Workbench, it doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run the scripts ? Something went wrong ?

Comment: "The old database should still be on my PC"<-- Did you try starting the database server to see if it fires up?  "I installed MariaDB on it and now when I open MySQL Workbench, it doesn't appear" <-- What doesn't appear? Your MariaDB, your old database? As far as your ipynb goes, did you point the creation script to your new MariaDB instance? Did it work? It feels like there are multiple questions here and none of them are terrible clear where we can help.

Comment: I can still see the Diagram of my old BDD

Yes, I tried running the scripts but they didn't work

I tried starting up the old database connection, that's there, but it only shows me the the databases I created on MariaDB

Comment: MySQL databases by default exist within a MySQL folder structure on the disk. Did you look for a old MYSQL instalation?

Comment: _I can still see the Diagram of my old BDD_ In what? Using what to see it??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried looking for it manually and with the file explorer (Windows 10) but couldn't find the database dor some reason (maybe I deleted it while cleaning the PC but I don't think so)

Comment: On MySQL Workbench, on the models tab, I can see my the diagram of the old database

Comment: Well if you cannot find it, its gone!

Comment: I dont think the existance of the model means there is any database there. If you have not started a MySQL Instance, then you cannot be seeing a MySQL database. You cannot see a MySQL database without there being a MySQL installed and running. Its not like an access database

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... but I still have some scripts I used to create it, I don't really care about the data on it, I just wanted to replicate the structure

Comment: Ok so run the scripts. There may be some incompatibilities, but sort those out when they happen

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.